# Crash at layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath with index out of bounds

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I do have a crash issue in my app where I have implemented custom layout collection view to show book pages in iPhone. When I do re ordering of pages (ex - if I want to pace the last to 1st place in the book) the app some times crashes in my custom layout code (layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath). Looking deeper into the code found that API is receiving in indexPath which is out of bounds. The row value is too big which is converting to -1 and since there will be no data at this location in my layout attributes array, the app crashes. This happens on iOS 9.x and not on 10.x.

Does anyone know why I am getting this crash.

PS: Stacktrace attached.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath()`:

```
override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    return cache[indexPath.item]
}
```

[I found this solution here and it solved my problem](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/45082)